# How to compare 2 Excel Workbooks without using Macros or VBA in Automation Anywhere?(Only using the Commands that are available in AA)

Tags: excel, automation, comparison, rpa, automationanywhere

This is to create a bot that updates the existing CSV file with the latest available data from the new CSV file that is downloaded at regular intervals.

I am unable to figure out the logic. Need your help.

Step 1: I am accessing the following website,
https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/stockresearch/globalmarkets/intIndices.asp

Step 2: I am downloading the Tables from the above website and saving a CSV file.

Step 3: I am comparing the OLD CSV file with the NEW CSV FILE and updating the values in the OLD CSV.

Step 4: If there were changes made there is a status column and in the corresponding row I need to update "Value Updated" or "Latest Value Exists"

Comment: You can use Microsoft Text Engine provider to connect to CSV file as database and basically query out the fields that you want to compare.

Answer (score 0):

When you extract data from CSVs/Excel workbooks you can set a session name other than Default. By doing so this will allow you to build for each functions to loop through both file, comparing and flagging differences if needed.

You should make sure that the indexes counted in the for loops are the correct ones as some mix ups could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Read the excel using database commands and then compare between them.

Answer (score 0):

**There are multiple ways to do that externally & internally -**

Let's talk about one of the ALGO(Only using the Commands that are available in AA) -

STEP 1 : OPEN BOTH CSV's IN DIFFERENT SESSIONS AND GET THE COLUMNS(WHICH NEEDS TO BE COMPARED) SAVED TO INDIVIDUAL LISTS.

FOR EX: IF I HAD TO COMPARE COLUMN 1's DATA OF X.CSV WITH  COLUMN 2's DATA OF Y.CSV THEN,

A) CAPTURE COLUMN 1 DATA OF X.CSV (FILEDATA COLUMN) TO LIST - lstColumn1

B) CAPTURE COLUMN 2 DATA OF Y.CSV (FILEDATA COLUMN) TO LIST - lstColumn2

STEP 2 : COMPARE BOTH DATA

FOR EX :
A) COMPARE -

```
    IF (lstColumn1=lstColumn2)

    GO TO ("PLEASE MENTION CELL NUMBER")

    UPDATE WITH "SPECIFIED VALUE"
```

This logic will provide you the best case results with respect to time complexity and without using the external code. You can, however, achieve a quicker one with a metabot implementation.

For downloading a similar use case bot you can visit this link - https://botstore.automationanywhere.com/bot/excel_comparison/